# How to create Assembly file from Object File using armcc compiler in windows platform?

Tags: compilation, arm

In our project, the makefile is using armcc compiler for compiling the code. i am using windows platform for compilation.

For one of the abort issue, i wanted to **generate assembly file from object file**. i dont know the command to use. please let me know if anybody knows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate assembly from an object file with

```
fromelf --disassemble --output foo.s foo.o
```

Alternatively, you can generate assembly direct from the compiler with

```
armcc -S foo.c
```